# How to Proceed in Solving this Equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, integral-inequality

Let $f: [0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ a non-decreasing function. Then show this inequality holds for all $x,y,z$ such that $0\le x<y<z$.
\begin{align*} & (z-x)\int_{y}^{z}f(u)\,\mathrm{du}\ge (z-y)\int_{x}^{z}f(u)\,\mathrm{du} \end{align*}

Can anyone help me?

Today in the morning I was trying out this problem and I was able to do up until this point before getting stuck. Please help me proceed further.

Here is my attempt at a solution.

Given
\begin{align*} & (z-x)\int_{y}^{z}f(u)\,\mathrm{du}\ge (z-y)\int_{x}^{z}f(u)\,\mathrm{du} \end{align*}\begin{align*} & \Longrightarrow(z-x)\int_{y}^{z}f(u)\,\mathrm{du}\ge (z-y)\int_{x}^{y}f(u)+(z-y)\int_{y}^{z}f(u)\,\mathrm{du} \end{align*}\begin{align*} & \Longrightarrow(y-x)\int_{y}^{z}f(u)\,\mathrm{du}\ge (z-y)\int_{x}^{y}f(u)\,\mathrm{du} \end{align*}\begin{align*} & \Longrightarrow(y-x)(f(z)-f(y))\,\mathrm\ge (z-y)(f(y)-f(x))\,\mathrm\ \end{align*}\begin{align*} & \Longrightarrow(y-x)f(z)+(z-y)f(x)\,\mathrm\ge (z-x)f(y)\mathrm\ \end{align*}
**Note:** If my approach is wrong or inefficient, please let me know: I'd be happy to learn new methods.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't start with what you're trying to prove.  Note that the result you're trying to prove is intuitively obvious if you divide both sides by $(z-y)(z-x)$ : The average value over $[y,z]$ is larger than the average value over $[x,z]$ because the function is bigger over $[x,y]$ than $[y,z]$.  Basically this is like saying the average of 2, 4, and 5 is bigger than the average of 1, 2, 4 and 5.

Try proving that the average of 3 numbers $b\leq c\leq d$ is greater than the average of the 4 numbers $a\leq b \leq c \leq d$.  Then you can try to generalize this result to integrals by breaking up the interval you're integrating over into two pieces.